# Where do I put a configuration when using windows services, webservices and websites?

Tags: c#, asp.net, config

**Problem:**
I'm developing in ASP .NET with C# and I want to validate e-mails.
For that I'm using a regular expression (let's call it EmailRegularExpressionValidator) and my problem is where schould I put the regex to easily change them if I want/need to with no need to recompile the code.
The validation is made in "IntermediateServices", in business layer, where all the things come to do theirs things.

**Solution 1:** web.config

I have lots of windows services and wich one have theirs own config. If I put EmailRegularExpressionValidator in that I have to write in all and when I change one I have to change all. Not good.

**Solution 2:** DB

Sometimes, I have to validate 1000 mails (or even even more), and if I put EmailRegularExpressionValidator in database I have to do 1000 querys to know EmailRegularExpressionValidator value. I think put it in memory but I have webservices. Not a good idea soo.

**Solution 3:** Resources

Resources can only be easily changed if in website. When I put them in business layer I cannot change them easily.

**Solution 4:** BD + Session

Like I say after, I'm using webservices....

Hope I was been explicit and hope you can help me.

Sorry about my english (greetings from Portugal).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a smarter way...

Instead edit machine.config as suggested I simply use cache who do the magic I want!

You can find a good article about how you can use it here: http://codemaverick.blogspot.pt/2007/01/caching-in-windows-application-i-was_8639.html

Answer (score 1):

In your case i would recommend config files.
.NET configuration files have an hierarchy, and it all starts in the machine.config, and all .NET applications read settings from that config.

If you don't override the keys on the applications config files, the application will use the settings from the machine.config. It is the most central point and can be used for all applications, change once, it changes for all.

It can be found here: 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\

Then after that depends on the framework you are using,

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG

or here:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config

Example:
Just place this after the `<configuration>` tag in the machine.config.

```
<appSettings><add key="myParameter" value="myValue"/></appSettings>
```

then in your code,

```
Configuration con = ConfigurationManager.OpenMachineConfiguration();
ConfigurationSection consec = con.Sections["myParameter"];
```

You must add a reference to System.Configuration

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think it is a good solution but is it safe? And when I install my application I have to remember to modify de machine.key. I think that modify files inside Windows folder is never a good politic.

Comment: Its safer for each application to use their config files, but if you want to configure all the applications on the machine the machine.config is just for that. It is used by .NET for a variety of things, like encryption... the idea of a machine config file is to maintain configuration information
for the server or machine as whole to aid in deployment, scalability,
performance and efficiency of the applications running on that machine.

Comment: You say, "And when I install my application I have to remember to modify de machine.key", this is going to be server applications right? Like websites and windowsservices, this is not going to be installed in any client?! If it is going to be installed in clients, you must use application config, not machine config. Machine.config is for server applications, that you have control.

Comment: The installation is made in 2 ways or SaaS (Software as a Service) where we have the application in our servers, or On Premisses where we have to install application in client servers... Anyway it's a very good answer and I'm thinking using it =) thanks